# Restricted access issues - Google Colaboratory

Tags: google-colaboratory

The program by which the day is for picture learning of AI using Google Colaboratory, continuously.
It was being carried out, time which made them learn was total of 3-about 4 hours, the one of the program
When trying to execute other programs during execution, the following message was output.

> It can't be connected to gpu at present because I reached the amount of consumption upper limit in colab.

Would there be a point that you pay attention by use of Google Colaboratory to avoid the symptom the following symptom generated after message output?

- It couldn't be reconnected any more this daytime.
- Even if a program wasn't executed, one after the next day just connected to GPU and reached the gpu amount of consumption upper limit.
- When GPU could be connected, during executing a program, I reach the amount of consumption upper limit by a short time.